# Session variable doesn't get the right value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, mysqli

When I submit my form the $_SESSION is always becoming 3, even when it's not supposed to be. For example, if I submit my form with the dropdown list selected as 1 which is supposed to make the session = 1, it is still returning 3 for some reason. I don't think the error is in my form but I may be wrong and I have checked my PHP a thousand times and can't find any error. Also, the user is inserted into the database but with the session variable of 3, not the actual one. I have included the PHP file in the form file for ajax, maybe that's the issue but I don't know how to get around it. P.S Sorry for the long code, I put it in so I don't get unnecessary questions in the comments. Also, this is actually a test on localhost so I'm not caring about SQL injections.

PHP

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    $link = mysqli_connect("****", "****", "****", "****");
    
     
    if(mysqli_connect_error()) {
         
         die("Couldn't connect to the database. try again later.");
         
     } 

     
      
    
      $query = "SELECT * FROM `users`";

      if($result = mysqli_query($link, $query)) {
          
          $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
          
      }
        $_SESSION['fa'] = "1";
    if(isset($_POST['fa'])) {
        $_SESSION['fa'] = "1";
    }
    
    if(isset($_POST['pa'])) {
        $_SESSION['fa'] = "2";
    }
    if(isset($_POST['pra'])) {
        $_SESSION['fa'] = "3";
    }

        $signupButton = "";
        $username = "";
        $password = "";
        $termsandconditions = "";
        
        if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
          if(isset($_POST['username'])) {
          $username = signupform_input($_POST["username"]); }
          
          if(isset($_POST['password'])) {
          $password = signupform_input($_POST["password"]); }
          
          if(isset($_POST['signupButton'])) {
          $signupButton = signupform_input($_POST["signupButton"]); }
          
          if(isset($_POST['termsandconditions'])) {
          $termsandconditions = signupform_input($_POST["termsandconditions"]); }
        }

        function signupform_input($data) {
          $data = trim($data);
          $data = stripslashes($data);
          $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
          return $data;
        }
    

        $usernameError = "";
        $passwordError = "";
        $termsandconditionsError = "";
        $error = "";

        if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
          
            if (empty($_POST["username"])) {
            $usernameError = "Username is required.";
            echo $usernameError;
          } else {
            $username = signupform_input($_POST["username"]);
          }
          if (empty($_POST["password"])) {
            $passwordError = " Password is required.";
            echo $passwordError;
          } else {
            $password = signupform_input($_POST["password"]);
          }
         
            
        if(isset($_POST['loginActive'])) {
          if($_POST['loginActive'] == "0" && $usernameError == "" && $passwordError == "" && $termsandconditionsError == "") {
              
              $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '". mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['username'])."' LIMIT 1"; 
              $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
              if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                    
                  $error = "That username is already taken.";
                  echo $error;
              } else {
                 
                  echo "<p style='color: green'>Hi</p>";
                  $query = "INSERT INTO `users` (`username`, `password`, `plan`) VALUES ('". mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['username'])."', '". mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['password'])."', '". mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_SESSION['fa'])."')";
                  mysqli_query($link, $query);
                  echo $query;
                  echo $_SESSION['fa'];
                  print_r($_POST);
              }
              
          } 
            }
        } 
        
?>
```

Form and Ajax and Jquery

```
            <h4>Account Type <i class="far fa-question-circle info" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Whenever you have all free accounts checked, payment method should be hidden, but if not then click on any paid account and then click back!" height="16px"></i></h4>
            <p>Visit <a href="pricing.php">Plan</a> for pricing details.</p>
              <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary dropdown-toggle dropdownB" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" name="playerAccount">Player Account</button>
                <div class="dropdown-menu">
                  <input type="button" class="dropdown-item active dropdownI"value="Player: Free Account $0.00/Mo" class="FA" id="dfreePlayerAccount" name="fa">
                  <input type="button" class="dropdown-item dropdownI" value="Player: Pro Account $5.99/Mo" class="FA" id="dproPlayerAccount" name="pa">
                    <input class="dropdown-item dropdownI" value="Player: Premium Account $9.99/Mo" class="FA" id="dpremiumPlayerAccount" name="pra">
                </div>
              </div>
                <br>
              <input type="radio" id="freePlayerAccount" class="free playAccount readonly" name="account" value="1" checked>
              <label for="freePlayerAccount">Player: Free Account $0.00/Mo</label><br>
              <input type="radio" id="proPlayerAccount" class="paid playAccount readonly" name="account" value="2">
              <label for="proPlayerAccount">Player: Pro Account $5.99/Mo</label><br>
              <input type="radio" id="premiumPlayerAccount" class="paid playAccount readonly" name="account" value="3">
              <label for="premiumPlayerAccount">Player: Premium Account $9.99/Mo</label><br>
              <hr>
              <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" name="dcreatorAccount">Creator Account&#40;Optional&#41;</button>
                <div class="dropdown-menu">
                  <a class="dropdown-item" value="2" class="CA" name="pca" id="dproCreatorAccount">Creator: Pro Account $9.99/Mo</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" value="3" class="CA" id="dpremiumCreatorAccount" name="prca">Creator: Premium Account $14.99/Mo</a>
                </div>
              </div> <br>
              <input type="radio" id="creatorProAccount" class="paid creatorAccount readonly" name="creatorAccount" value="5">
              <label for="creatorProAccount">Creator: Pro Account $9.99/Mo</label><br>
              <input type="radio" id="creatorPremiumAccount" class="paid creatorAccount readonly" name="creatorAccount" value="6">
              <label for="creatorPremiumAccount">Creator: Premium Account $14.99/Mo</label><br>
                <hr>
            <div class="hiddenPaymentMethod"> <h5>Payment Method</h5>
              <input type="radio" id="Paypal" name="payment" value="Paypal" class="payment">
              <label for="Paypal">Paypal</label><br>
              <input type="radio" id="creditCard" name="payment" value="CreditCard" class="payment">
              <label for="creditCard">Credit Card</label><br>
              <input type="text" style="display:none;" name="creditCardNumber" id="creditCardNumber" placeholder="Card Number">
              <input type="radio" id="debitCard" name="payment" value="DebitCard" class="payment">
          <label for="debitCard">Debit Card</label>
               <input type="text" style="display:none;" name="debitCardNumber" id="debitCardNumber" placeholder="Card Number"> 
                <br></div>
                <br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="termsAndConditions" class="conditions" name="termsandconditions" value="0">
            <label for="termsAndConditions"> I have read and agreed to the Terms and Conditions <span data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal"><i class="far fa-question-circle questionMark"></i></span></label>
            <p id="errors"></p>
            <p id="tacError" style="color:red"></p>
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" name="signupButton" id="signUpButton" value="Submit">
     
            <script type="text/javascript">
      
                $("#signUpButton").click(function() { 
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "actionSignUp.php",
                        data: "username=" + $("#username").val() + "&password=" + $("#Password").val() + "&termsandconditions=" + $("#termsAndConditions").val() + $(".CA").val() + "&fa=" + $("#dfreePlayerAccount").val() + "&pa=" + $("#dproPlayerAccount").val() + "&pra=" + $("#dpremiumPlayerAccount").val() + "&pca=" + $("#dproCreatorAccount").val() + "&prca=" + $("#dpremiumCreatorAccount").val() + "&loginActive=" + $("#loginActive").val()
                    }).done(function(result)  {
                            $("#errors").html(result);
                        }).fail(function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        
                            alert("Error Requesting. Please Try Again Later.");
                        
                        });

                    }); 
                        function myFunction(event) {
                  event.stopPropagation();
                  document.getElementById("dropdownI").classList.toggle("show");
                        }

                // Close the dropdown menu if the user clicks outside of it
                window.onclick = function(event) {
                  document.getElementById("dropdownI").classList.remove("show");
                }
                $("#dproPlayerAccount").click(function(){
                    
                    $("#dproPlayerAccount").css("background-color", "#157AF6");
                    $("#dproPlayerAccount").css("color", "white");
                    $("#dfreePlayerAccount").css("background-color", "white");
                    $("#dfreePlayerAccount").css("color", "black");
                    $("#dpremiumPlayerAccount").css("background-color", "white");
                    $("#dpremiumPlayerAccount").css("color", "black");
                })
                $("#dfreePlayerAccount").click(function(){
                    
                    $("#dfreePlayerAccount").css("background-color", "#157AF6");
                    $("#dfreePlayerAccount").css("color", "white");
                    $("#dproPlayerAccount").css("background-color", "white");
                    $("#dproPlayerAccount").css("color", "black");
                    $("#dpremiumPlayerAccount").css("background-color", "white");
                    $("#dpremiumPlayerAccount").css("color", "black");
                })
                $("#dpremiumPlayerAccount").click(function(){
                    
                    $("#dpremiumPlayerAccount").css("background-color", "#157AF6");
                    $("#dpremiumPlayerAccount").css("color", "white");
                    $("#dfreePlayerAccount").css("background-color", "white");
                    $("#dfreePlayerAccount").css("color", "black");
                    $("#dproPlayerAccount").css("background-color", "white");
                    $("#dproPlayerAccount").css("color", "black");
                })
                $("#dfreePlayerAccount").click(function(){
                    
                    $("#freePlayerAccount").prop('checked', 'checked');
                })
                $("#dproPlayerAccount").click(function(){
                    
                    $("#proPlayerAccount").prop('checked', 'checked');
                })
                $("#dpremiumPlayerAccount").click(function(){
                    
                    $("#premiumPlayerAccount").prop('checked', 'checked');
                })
                $("#dfreeCreatorAccount").click(function(){
                    
                    $("#creatorFreeAccount").prop('checked', 'checked');
                })
                $("#dproCreatorAccount").click(function(){
                    
                    $("#creatorProAccount").prop('checked', 'checked');
                })
                $("#dpremiumCreatorAccount").click(function(){
                    
                    $("#creatorPremiumAccount").prop('checked', 'checked');
                })
                    $('input:checkbox').change(
                        function(){
                            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                                $(this).val("1");
                            } else {
                                $(this).val("0");
                            }
                        });
                    
                     $("#signUpButton").click(function(){
                        
                        if($(".conditions").val() == "0") {
                            $("#tacError").html("Terms and Conditions are required");
                        } else {
                            
                            $("#tacError").html("");
                        }
                    })
                   
                    $('#dproPlayerAccount').click(
                        function(){
                                $(".hiddenPaymentMethod").show();
                                $("#Paypal").attr('checked', 'checked');
                            
                        });
                    $('#dpremiumPlayerAccount').click(
                        function(){
                                $(".hiddenPaymentMethod").show();
                                $("#Paypal").attr('checked', 'checked');
                            
                        });
                    $('#dfreePlayerAccount').click(
                        function(){
                                $(".hiddenPaymentMethod").hide();
                                $("#Paypal").removeAttr('checked');                            
                        });
                        
                        $('#dpremiumCreatorAccount').click(
                        function(){
                                $(".hiddenPaymentMethod").show();
                                $("#Paypal").attr('checked', 'checked');
                            
                        });
                    $('#dproCreatorAccount').click(
                        function(){
                                $(".hiddenPaymentMethod").show();
                                $("#Paypal").attr('checked', 'checked');
                            
                        });  
                        
                    $('input:radio[name="payment"]').change(
                        function(){
                            if ($(this).is(':checked') && $(this).val() == 'CreditCard') {
                                $("#creditCardNumber").show();
                            }
                        });
                    
                    $('input:radio[name="payment"]').change(
                        function(){
                            if ($(this).is(':checked') && $(this).val() == 'Paypal' || $(this).val() == 'DebitCard') {
                                $("#creditCardNumber").hide();
                            }
                        });
                
                    $('input:radio[name="payment"]').change(
                        function(){
                            if ($(this).is(':checked') && $(this).val() == 'DebitCard') {
                                $("#debitCardNumber").show();
                            }
                        });
                    
                    $('input:radio[name="payment"]').change(
                        function(){
                            if ($(this).is(':checked') && $(this).val() == 'Paypal' || $(this).val() == 'CreditCard') {
                                $("#debitCardNumber").hide();
                            }
                        });
                     $(function () {
                      $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
                    })
            </script>
```

Comment: Try `if(isset($_POST['fa']) && !empty($_POST['fa']))` do this for all and see

Comment: It didn't do anything.

Comment: This is my printed arrays: INSERT INTO `users` (`username`, `password`, `plan`) VALUES ('gg', 'gg son', '3')3Array ( [username] => gg [password] => gg son [termsandconditions] => 1undefined [fa] => Player: Free Account $0.00/Mo [pa] => Player: Pro Account $5.99/Mo [pra] => Player: Premium Account $9.99/Mo [pca] => [prca] => [loginActive] => 0 )

Comment: The users, user names, and password field actually have backticks in them but SO recognized them as code instead,